Unable to use associations on a view after Hibernate update
This is the scenario:
There is a one-to-many association between EntityA and EntityB:
@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityA")
class EntityA {
    @Id
    Long idEntityA;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<EntityB> entitiesB;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EntityB")
class EntityB {
    @Id
    Long idEntityB;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idEntityA")
    private EntityA entityA;
}

There is also a database view which contais a subset of EntityA records. It has its own entity representation:
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_EntityA")
class ViewEntityA {
    @Id
    Long idEntityA;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<EntityB> entitiesB;
}

I've been able to use the association ViewEntityA.entitiesB without any problem until  the upgrade to SpringBoot3 and Hibernate 6.
Now if I try to access any ViewEntityA.entitiesB I got this error:

Association
'mypackage.ViewEntityA.entitiesB' is
'mappedBy' a property named 'entityA' which references the wrong
entity type 'mypackage.EntityA', expected
'mypackage.ViewEntityA'

Is there any way to make it work again?

Note that it was always incorrect.  That it happened to work before your software updates was an (un)happy accident.

Perhaps there is a way to configure your persistence provider (Hibernate) to accept this strange state of affairs, but even if so, I'm inclined to think that it would be better to pay off the technical debt rolled up in this clunky design ASAP.  Possibly you want to engage entity inheritance.  Possibly you want to switch from a view to a named query.  Possibly you want something else.  But the longer you wait to fix this, the more it's going cost when eventually you have to do.

After a couple days I found a solution using @JoinColumn:
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_EntityA")
class ViewEntityA {
    @Id
    Long idEntityA;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "idEntityA", referencedColumnName = "idEntityA")
    Set<EntityB> entitiesB;
}

With this Hibernate was able to create the correct SQL queries and retrieve the EntityB collection filtered by idEntityA.
PS.: I understand this may not be the best solution. I don't even know if @JoinColumn should be used like this. I will do more research on it but sometimes you need a fast solution to a real-life problem that can't wait.
